# get parts of a URL in Flex from a string

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I am trying to parse out pieces of a url string for comparison in Flex. I am really new to flex so just going to write what I want to do not sure if this code would be valid.

```
// urlone: http://www.helloworld.com/hello
// urltwo: http://www.goodbye.com/
public function compareURLHost(urlone:String,urltwo:String):Boolean
{
   var displayURL:URL = URL(urlone);
   var compareURL:URL = URL(urltwo);

   // compare www.helloworld.com to www.goodbye.com
   if(displauURL.hostname == compareURL.hostname)
      return true;

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [URLUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64e50-7ff8.html).  You can get the port, hostname, serverName, etc.

Answer (score 0):

URLUtils can help, but they're not always what you need. For example, I had a project where I needed to remove a single directory from a url. It may sound dumb, but the client wanted their publicly viewable XML file to not show actual URLs and that was their solution. In that case, I did:

```
var url:String = "http://someurl.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext"
url = url.slice(url.indexOf('dir1'),5); //the four chars of the url + "/"
trace (url); //http://someurl.com/dir2/file.ext
```

You can also use String.replace to replace a set of characters with another set (say if my client had wanted to hide the url by swapping calling dir1 dir5 in the url)

```
var url:String = "http://someurl.com/dir5/dir2/file.ext"
var patten:RegExp = /dir5/;
url.replace(pattern,"dir1");
trace (url); //http://someurl.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext
```